# How to properly update nested data in redux

Tags: immutability, redux

This is my current object which i need to update:

```
 [
    { id: q1, 
      answers:[
                { id: a1, 
                  answered: false 
                },
                ...
              ]  
    },
    ...
 ]
```

I can't figure out how to update this object and set for example answered = true. 
Is there any better way saving this kind of object? I tried to use the [update](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) addon from React but can't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the answers list this way, in your reducer:

```
function update(state, action) {
    // assuming you are passing an id of the item to be updated via action.itemId
    let obj = state.whatever_list.filter(item => item.id === action.itemId)[0]

    //assuming you are passing an id of the answer to be updated via action.answerId
    //also, assuming action.payload contains {answered: true}
    let answers = obj.answers.map(answer => answer.id === action.answerId ? 
                                            Object.assign({}, answer, action.payload) : answer)
    obj = Object.assign({}, obj, {answers: answers})
    return {
        whatever_list: state.whatever_list.map(item => item.id == action.itemId? Object.assign({}, item, obj) : item)
    }
}
```

Here is what your action might look like:

```
function updateAnswer(itemId, answerId, payload) {
    return {
        type: UPDATE_ANSWER,
        itemId: itemId,
        answerId: answerId,
        payload: payload
    }
}
```

In your react component class, assuming there is an event handler for monitoring whether if a question is answered:

```
export default class Whatever extends React.Component {

    ...

    // assuming your props contains itemId and answerId
    handleAnswered = (e) => {
        this.props.dispatch(updateAnswer(this.props.itemId, this.props.answerId, {answered: true})) 
    }

    ...
}
```

So basically what happens is this:

1. Your event handler calls the action and pass the updated data to it
2. When your action is called, it returns the updated data along with a type parameter
3. When your reducer sees the type parameter, the corresponding handler will be triggered (the first piece of the code above)
4. The reducer will pull out the existing data from the list, replace the old data with the new one, and then return a list containing the new data

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sub-reducer for the answers key. Look at this example:

https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/async/reducers/index.js

Comment: This is already a sub reducer. I don't want to split them one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) and an update would be as simple as:

```
return dotProp.set(state, 'quiz.0.answers.0.answered', true);
```